# Subtracting/Adding the data from previous row in a different column in a pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

| Id | Company | SD | ED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A111 | ABC | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2001 |
| A111 | ABC | 1/1/2001 | 1/1/2005 |
| A111 | DEF | 1/1/2005 | 1/1/2010 |
| A111 | GHI | 1/1/2010 |  |
| B111 | JKL | 1/1/2006 | 1/1/2007 |
| B111 | JKL | 1/1/2010 | 1/1/2011 |
| B111 | JKL | 1/1/2011 | 1/1/2012 |
| B111 | JKL | 1/1/2012 | 1/1/2014 |
| B111 | JKL | 1/1/2014 |  |
| C111 | ABC | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2002 |
| C111 | DEF |  | 1/1/2004 |
| C111 | GHI | 1/1/2005 |  |
| C111 | JKL | 1/1/2007 |  |

This is what the expected output:

| Id | Company | SD | ED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A111 | ABC | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2005 |
| A111 | DEF | 1/1/2005 | 1/1/2010 |
| A111 | GHI | 1/1/2010 |  |
| B111 | JKL | 1/1/2006 |  |
| C111 | ABC | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2002 |
| C111 | DEF | 1/2/2002 | 1/1/2004 |
| C111 | GHI | 1/1/2005 | 12/31/2006 |
| C111 | JKL | 1/1/2007 |  |

Basically what I have to do here is:

1. If Id is same then for each unique company names calculate min(SD) and max (ED). Will make ED as blank later on based on another condition(employee status as active) which is not needed here.
2. If Id is same for each unique company names calculate min(SD) and max (ED), but if SD is null then take the ED of previous company and add +1 day to ED to get SD. Similarly if ED is blank then subtract -1 day from SD (SD - 1) to get ED.

Now I have the result for part it's straight forward group by on Id, Company Name and min(SD) and max(SD). Following is the code that I have used:

```
 result_agg = result.groupby(["EID", "CLEAN_NAME"]).agg({"Start_Date":[min],"End_Date":[max]})
 result_agg.columns = ['Start_Date', 'End_Date']
 result_agg = result_agg.reset_index()
 result_agg.head()
```

The second part is where I am having trouble. I thought if using shift() but not sure how to use it.

Also what I did in this case was I created a new ED column and shifted all the values in the previous ED column to 1 row below so basically 1st row in old ED column will be 2nd row in new ED column and added +1 day to it.

Also aggregation is somewhat easy but I stumbled upon a particular case where using aggregation isn't a solution. For example an employee can work in company ABC from 1/1/2002 till 1/1/2003 then DEF, GHI and then rejoins ABC in let's say 1/1/2010...in this case if I use aggregation wherein I group by company name the min start date and max end date will be incorrect for company ABC...

Any leads would be appreciated. Thank you.!

Comment: This looks like the [exact same question as previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082356/create-a-list-from-a-dataframe-in-python), you should rather improve the question from yesterday

Comment: @mozway: I thought of discarding that question and create a new one with better details.? Can I delete yesterday's question.? And any leads with respect to the solution.?